# Opening a terminal, running a command, and leaving an interactive terminal open

Tags: command-line, xterm

I don't have high hopes for this, but what I'm trying to do is create a Desktop shortcut that, when clicked, opens a terminal (preferably mate-terminal, but I'm not picky), runs a command, and leaves the terminal open in an **interactive session**. Ideally, I would be able to arrow up in the new window to rerun the command.

Things I have tried:

- `mate-terminal --command "bash -c 'ls;$SHELL'"`: I cannot see what command was run and I cannot arrow up to rerun the command.
- `Changing the MATE terminal preferences to Keep Open`: It keeps the window open, but it's not interactive. All I can do is close it.
- `xterm -hold -e 'bash -c "ls"&&$SHELL'`: I cannot see what command was run and I cannot arrow up to rerun the command.

What I'm trying to do is create a shortcut for a command-line application that opens a terminal and runs `whatevertool -h` and then just waits for the user to do what they need to do. Is what I want possible?

Comment: Yes, its definitely possible. When you use `bash -c` by itself, it corresponds to "Read and execute commands from the first non-option argument command_string, then exit" You can have bash start in interactive shell mode with the `bash -i` options, which will automatically read your `.bashrc` configuration file, as well as  should also give you command history access wth up/down arrows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply try combining `--rcfile` option and amending history.

```
export CMD="ls -h ."  && mate-terminal --command  "bash -c 'bash --rcfile <(echo \" history -s '\''$CMD'\''; $CMD\")' "
```

If the command being run is more complex, I'd use an explicit script rather than complex command-to-file redirection that involves quoting problems

```
mate-terminal --command  "bash --rcfile cmd.sh "
```

where cmd.sh is

```
#!/bin/bash
CMD="ls -lh ."
history -s "$CMD"
$CMD
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Install `expect` and write the following expect script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn bash
expect "$ "
send "yourcommand\r"
interact
```

(If your shell prompt ends with something different than "$ " - eg. you plan to run this from root - change it appropriately in the third line.)

Configure your GNOME or MATE terminal profile to run this script instead of the shell and start the terminal using that profile (eg. `gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=PROFILENAME` - make a shortcut to run this command).

That should do what you want: you will see the command being run and should be able to retun to it with up-arrow, and the terminal stays interactive after the command ends.

Comment: This is a great suggestions as well. I ended up creating a script `#!/usr/bin/expect
set cmd [lindex $argv 0];
spawn bash
expect "$ "
send "$cmd\r"
interact`, then `mate-terminal --command "expect test.sh 'sqlmap -h'"`